# What is the spectral radius of $PBD$ with $P$ projection, $\|B\|_\infty=1$, and $D$ diagonal with $\|D\|_2<1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume we have the matrix product:
$$A=PBD$$

where $P$ is a projection matrix (i.e., $P=P^2$, $P=P^\top$, and $\|P\|_2=1$), $B$ is a matrix whose infinite norm is equal to one ($\|B\|_\infty=1$), and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose $\ell_2$-norm is less than one ($\|D\|_2<1$).

Is it correct to say that the spectral radius of $A$ is less than 1 ($\rho(A)< 1$). If yes, how to prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** the old answer is wrong. Here is a correction.

No. Counterexample: let $0<c<1$ and
$$
P=\pmatrix{\frac{16}{25}&-\frac{12}{25}\\ -\frac{12}{25}&\frac{9}{25}},\ B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ -1&0},\ D=cI,
\ A=PBD=\pmatrix{\frac{28}{25}r&0\\ -\frac{21}{25}r&0}.
$$
Then $\rho(A)=\frac{28}{25}c>1$ when $c$ is close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your useful response. One additional question. If I have a block diagonal matrix $D$ instead of a diagonal one where each block $D_i$ is symmetric and $\|D_i\|_2<1$. Furthermore, I know that $D$ is diagonally dominant. Is it possible to prove that $\rho(A)<1$?

Comment: @user293017 The $D$ in the counterexample given in my answer is symmetric and diagonally dominant. Numerically $D\approx r\pmatrix{-0.9487&-0.3162\\ -0.3162&0.9487}$. So, using the $P,B$ and $D$ in the remark, $\pmatrix{P\\ &P}\pmatrix{B\\ &B}\pmatrix{D\\ &D}$ gives you a counterexample to your new conjecture..